# Pthred_exit()

Tags: pthread

На сайте какой-то там буржуйской лаборатории в мануале по потокам POSIX есть есть пример кода с использованием pthreads. Он просто показывает, что программа рандомно переключается с основного процесса на его поток и обратно.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_THREADS     5   
void *PrintHello(void *threadid){
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long t;
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
      printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
      if (rc){
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
      }
   }

   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/samples/hello.out - один из вариантов вывода.

Так вот меня смущают последние две строчки кода. Зачем нам вызывать лишний раз **pthread_exit(NULL)**; если мы вызывали его уже в ***PrintHello(void* threadid)**?

У Танненбаума в книге "Современные ОС" есть почти такой же код, но он не вызывает лишний раз **pthread_exit(NULL)** (двух строк нет). 
Я думаю, что Танненбаум прав (поправте, если не так). Но как убедиться в этом? Как вот заставить pthread_exit вывести на экран сообщение типа я поток номер три завершил себя, и быть уверенным, что поток действительно завершился? Я сразу же подумал после pthread_exit в PrintHello выводить сообщение, но до этой строчки же управление не доходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_exit(NULL)` завершает "текущий" поток - поток, который вызвал эту функцию. Поэтому, будучи вызванным в последней строке main, он завершит всю программу (завершение главного потока завершает программу). Конечно, там можно было написать просто `return 0;` но видимо автор решил показать свои знания.

Узнать, что поток завершился можно с помощью [pthread_join](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/ipcbook/node48.html). Поток просто будет ждать завершения другого потока. Дождавшись завершения, может вывести любое сообщение.

Comment: Действительно!! Main() это же тоже поток. Кто бы мог подумать))
Спасибо. А была опасность с самого начала неправильно понимать.

Comment: Добавлю, что pthread_join() вызовет **приостановку** вызвавшего потока, до завершения "опрашиваемого" (вообще в оригинале target thread) и не применим к detached потокам. 

Если Вы не хотите ждать (или надо проверить detached thread), то вызывайте pthread_kill(pthread_t thread, 0) и проверяйте код возврата. Только в бесконечном цикле не стоит так опрашивать.

Для корректной работы в такой ситуации потоки совместно используют функции pthread_mutex_lock(), pthread_mutex_unlock(), pthread_cond_timedwait() и pthread_cond_broadcast() или posix семафоры.